# I want to set a selectList to a value based on a field in the Database from Class constructor

Tags: apex, selectlist

I have a selectList on my page. I want to be able to set the default value based on a field in the Contact being loaded. Is there a way to do this from the constructor?

As a secondary question it would be great to be able to only display some options again based on preferences in a field in the Contact. What would be the best way to accomplish that? Either build the selectList options or set render to false?

```
public String county {get;set;}

public List<SelectOption> getCountyList() {
    List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
    options.add(new SelectOption('0','Antrim'));
    options.add(new SelectOption('2','Armagh'));
    ...lots more options here...
    options.add(new SelectOption('60','Wexford'));
    options.add(new SelectOption('62','Wicklow'));
    return options;
}

contactInfo = [SELECT Are_you_an_Engineer__c, Best_described__c, 
               Preferred_Counties_for_Volunteering__c, Home_County__c 
               FROM Contact WHERE Id = :conID];

        if (county == null) {CountyList.set('Waterford'); } //would like this to be whatever Home_County__c is but doesn't work for just 'Waterford' Tells me CountyList doesn't exist.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can assign the literal "value" to the backing variable. Since they're using numbered identifiers, it would look like this:

```
if(county == null) { county = '62'; }
```

You could even use a ternary operator to select one of two values, like this:

```
county = contact.Home_County__c == null? '62': contact.Home_County__c;
```

You can generate your list dynamically based on the contact. I wouldn't normally recommend using `rendered="false"` for each select option in the Visualforce page itself, because it uses up view state (limited to 135k) and is slightly slower to render than calculating everything on the Apex Code side, and you can even make the list transient so it doesn't use view state.

Comment: Yeah, but the value stored on the database is the string value.  I'd need to translate it and the SelectList already does that so it'd be best if I didn't have to do it again separately.

Comment: Weird, I can edit your answer but I can't edit my comment, Ha.

So I guess the best bet might be to set the values to what is on the database and alter my code to use that. 

Any chance of an example in building the selectlist dynamically or a link to one?

Thanks for the replies.

Comment: I think you may need to focus on what you're actually doing. I wouldn't use index numbers to strings like that in the picklist unless I had a good reason. For example, you could make an array of items ( `['Antrim','Armagh',...,'Wexford','Wicklow']`, and you could generate the picklist from those items in a loop, and then look up the item by index. For loading from the contact, though, you'd want to load the contact first, and in the generation loop, if the contact's value matches the picklist item, set the default value then.